# arm6 devices showing much higher memory usage

Tags: ios, memory, xamarin.ios, instruments, armv7

I have built an app in MonoTouch - it works with both arm6 and arm7 devices, I've tried to be as careful as possible with my memory usage and on the arm7 devices it works beautifully - running it through the apple instruments program I can see an average 'live bytes' in the allocations tool of around 4MB.

However on the arm6 devices (iPhone 3G, iPod touch 2nd Gen) - it is instead showing memory usage of around 22MB - gives frequent low memory warnings and obviously eventually crashes.

Is there any build setting or any particular thing that anyone can think of that could be causing the app to have such a high memory footprint on the 3G device vs the 3GS (arm7) devices? 
It's especially frustrating as these devices have plenty of memory anyways.

Thanks for your time,

Liam

Answer (score 1):

That's a **huge** difference!

My *best* guess is that Apple's Instruments is **misreporting** the memory being used (in either or both case) and that, in fact, the **real** memory requirements of both are much closer.

In this case the older, **armv6**, devices have less RAM and will give low memory warnings before the newer, **armv7**, devices (with more RAM). IOW the behaviour you're seeing *could* be normal, i.e. you could be near the limits for older devices.

Now it could also be a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) or some other configuration that differs between your builds (e.g. a **Debug** versus a **Release** build). It would be helpful if you could share (or create a test case) this with us (Xamarin) so we can try to reproduce the issue.

**NOTE**:

I assume you're talking about a single, **armv6**, application used on different devices. But even if you used different builds (one for **arm6** and one for **armv7** or a **fat** application) this would only affect native code generation. As such it will affect the binary size but it *should not* have a (huge) effect on the runtime memory requirement of applications.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply - I've created a fat application (using LLVM) and a single Arm6 version. Both are release builds.  I wonder if the third-party library (Sparrow) could be having an effect? I have to compile and Lipo a fat binary version for LLVM to work and an arm6 only version to get the standard mono compiler to work but I'm not sure if the framework itself manages memory differently for older devices.  In the meantime I'll try and get a couple of tests done and post some screenshots of the results.